# RuntimeException в JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx

В JavaFX меня преследует проблема с загрузкой картинки на форму. Как бы я не пробовал загрузить ее, результат один - RuntimeException. Что я делаю не так ?

```
public class Main extends Application {
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Pane root = new Pane();

    Label label = new Label(); // метка с текстом
    label.setText("This is a label");


    Image image = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("D:\\1.png")); // тут RuntimeException
    ImageView img = new ImageView(image);
    img.setFitHeight(200);
    img.setFitWidth(250);

    Label labelImg = new Label();
    labelImg.setGraphic(img);
    labelImg.setTranslateX(75);
    labelImg.setTranslateY(100);

    root.getChildren().addAll(label, labelImg);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 400, 400);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Пробовал с текстовым файлом - загружается с диска без проблем. Значит путь верно указываю. Чем это может быть вызвано ?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте загружать изображение вот так:

```
File file = new File("image.png");
Image image = new Image(file.toURI().toString());
ImageView iv = new ImageView(image);
```

Comment: Исключения больше нет, но и картинка не рисуется.